# Chrome extension to flash the (Windows) taskbar?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is there an extension that will flash the Windows taskbar when there is a page update? For instance, if I'm using a browser-based chat client like Jabbr, can I have the taskbar flash when a message is posted?

Comment: Perhaps you should write one. This seems like a very narrow question, and would depend on the rules used to update a page.

Comment: If I knew the first thing about writing Chrome extensions I might write one, but I don't. It's not as narrow as you might think. More and more websites have dynamically updating content now, even more so now we have websockets. So we need a way of knowing when a background browser window has updated, right? A flashing taskbar is one idea. I had in mind something that flashed when the DOM changes OR, have a config that allows input of a selector on a per-site basis, like Adblock.